# Unchecking check_box_tag to enable text area after disabling it

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery to disable and re-enable a text area depending on whether a checkbox is checked or not.

I am able to disable the text area box when checkbox is checked, but unable to enable it when checkbox is unchecked. Here is my current Jquery script:

```
$('#business_closed').change(function(){
  value = $(this).val();
  console.log(value);

  if(value){
    $('#open_hours').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
  else{
    $('#open_hours').removeAttr("disabled");
  }
  return false;
});
```

Based on `console.log(value);`, my value is always 1 even when I am unchecking the checkbox. How do I get the value of the checkbox (whether or not it is checked)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified code: You should use checked properties

```
$('#business_closed').change(function(){

  console.log(value);

  if(this.checked){
    $('#open_hours').attr("disabled", true);
  }
  else{
    $('#open_hours').attr("disabled", false);
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. This.checked will evaluate to true once StackOverflow lets me :)

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your last sentence. do you still have any problem?

Comment: It was a weak pun - everything works. I'll mark your answer as correct after the imposed time limit. :)

Answer (score 1):

There re some problem associated with using `.attr()` with jQuery version < 1.6 .

As it give's the defaultCheck property at the time of page rendering. So its a good practice to use `.prop()` instead

```
if(value){
    $('#open_hours').prop("disabled", true);
  }
  else{
    $('#open_hours').prop("disabled", false);
  }
```